# Semantic UI CDNJs Links best practice to put with jquery in header or below footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

What is the best practice:

1. putting semantic ui cdnjs links in header under semantic ui css,
2. or put it in scripts tags below the footer of the page

I found a lot of guys just put it in the header with JQuery too, but as i know scripts must put under the page to be sure every element just created to give it anything with javascript.

Is it correct what i know or there is something i don't know about it? I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that generally scripts should be added at the end of the page, as they are loaded last there. This, however, doesn't guarantee that the DOM has been completely loaded at that time (like images etc.), therefore js that depends on that should always listen to the `$('document').ready()`-event and for that code it doesn't really matter where it is in the html. (A lot of people wrap everything in that listener even if it isn't necessary, just in case)

Bottom line, it is considered best-practice to put any scripts at the bottom of the html, but it isn't always necessary. I would probably do it anyways.

This will also make the js be loaded last and usually that is the least important part of your website (when loading).